# DLL load failed when importing PySide2, only while debugging

Tags: python, qt, pycharm, pydev, pyside2

Im facing a strange issue. I have downloaded and installed the Qt for Python library ([PySide2](http://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted.html)) in the virtual environment of my project in PyCharm. I have created a dummy GUI using the Qt Designer and Im loading (.ui file) and displaying the GUI through my python code. Whenever I run the code, I can see the GUI without errors. However, whenever I debug the code, I get an error:

File "...\gui_pyside2.py", line 5, in

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit
```

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.**

Pydev crashes on this line:

```
#execute the script (note: it's important to compile first to have the filename set in debug mode)
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
```

Im pretty lost on what could be the cause. It seems like pydev is interfering with the imports? I have tried using import statements instead of from import but the problem persists. Any ideas?

Versions installed:

- PyCharm Community 2018.1.4
- pydev debugger (build 181.5087.37)
- Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900
  64 bit (AMD64)]
- PySide2-5.11.1a1.dev1530373667-5.11.1.dist (technical preview, python binding to Qt 5.11)

Comment: try after updating your windows system, I had the same issue before, it was resolved after installing visual studio redistribution c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to my own question:

Turns out there's a compatibility setting in Pycharm for Pyside:

[image: PySide compatibility]

Set it to PySide and debugger runs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can so try to use PyCharm Community 2019